# Avoid ESOCKETTIMEDOUT from Google/Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, campaign-monitor

I have a Firebase cloud function, that is looping through users in a database and sends an email to each one. It uses the Campaign Monitor API for Transactional/Smart Emails, but the request results in an ESOCKETTIMEDOUT error. Campaign Monitor receives and processes each request just fine, but I would like to avoid the error of course.

How can I do this? I've read elsewhere about a setting, 'agent: false, pool: {maxSockets: 100}', but I am not sure if this is the right approach - and I don't know where to set it on a Firebase og Google Cloud Function.

This is the request snippet, that is called by the loop.

```
  api.transactional.sendSmartEmail(details, function (err, res) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('error sending mail, err);
        /*Throws:
        { Error: ESOCKETTIMEDOUT
        at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/createsend-node/node_modules/request/request.js:813:19)
        at ClientRequest.g (events.js:292:16)
        at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
        at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:185:7)
        at TLSSocket.emitTimeout (_http_client.js:630:10)
        at TLSSocket.g (events.js:292:16)
        at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
        at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:185:7)
        at TLSSocket.Socket._onTimeout (net.js:338:8)
        at ontimeout (timers.js:386:11) code: 'ESOCKETTIMEDOUT', connect: false }
        */
    } else {
            console.log('sent mail');
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you edit your question to show exactly what is appearing in the log, and the line of code it corresponds to?

Comment: Thnx @DougStevenson, I've updated now

Comment: What payment plan is your Firebase project on?

Comment: "Blaze" it is called

Comment: You might want to ask the provider of the API what might be happening here.